# How does one, for nested arrays, rearrange the order in a way that the last string item of an array equals the first string item of the following one?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I need to achieve this result

```
[['peanuts', 'butter'], ['butter', 'jelly'], ['jelly', 'bananas'], ['bananas', 'apples']]
```

From this array

```
[['butter', 'jelly'], ['bananas', 'apples'], ['peanuts', 'butter'], ['jelly', 'bananas']]
```

I want the second element of each array to match the first element of the next one.

I think sort function is the best option here, but I have tried this and this doesn't work (actually works but not with all arrays somehow)

```
.sort(([a, b], [c, d]) => {
    return b === c ? -1 : 1
})
```

Comment: What is your criteria for sorting?

Comment: @iota every next [0] el of array should be the [1] el of previous array. Like [['a', 'b'], ['b', c'], ['c', 'd'], ['d', 'e'] etc

Comment: @MariaCornetti ... are there any questions left?

Comment: @PeterSeliger no, thank you!

Comment: @PeterSeliger you right, sorry, forgot it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting is not the best method to solve this problem. Instead, you can create lookup tables for the first and second elements and go through them in sequence.

```js
const arr = [
  ['butter', 'jelly'],
  ['bananas', 'apples'],
  ['peanuts', 'butter'],
  ['jelly', 'bananas']
];
const lookupFirst = {},
  lookupSecond = {};
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  lookupFirst[arr[i][0]] = i;
  lookupSecond[arr[i][1]] = i;
}
const next = arr.map(x => lookupFirst[x[1]]);
let curr = arr.findIndex(x => !lookupSecond[x[0]]);
const res = [];
do {
  res.push(arr[curr]);
} while ((curr = next[curr]) !== undefined);
console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorting will not help, instead one needs an algorithm which, for instance, starts by searching for the only array that does not have any matching item which links it to any of the other arrays.

This array's first item (a string) then is the link to this very arrays previous array that's last item does match the before mentioned first item.

The above described process `splice`s every matching array from the input value and collects (`unshift`) them within a result array, thus it mutates the input value, and therefore just needs to be continued until the input value got emptied.

```js
function getCopyInDominoesLikeOrder(list) {
  // in order to not directly mutate the input value.
  list = Array.from(list);

  // get the array where its last item does not match
  // any other array's first item, which makes it the
  // last array of the return value.
  let itemListIndex = list.findIndex(aList =>
    list.every(bList => aList[aList.length - 1] !== bList[0])
  );
  let itemList = list.splice(itemListIndex, 1)[0];

  const result = [itemList]; // return value.
  let firstItem = itemList[0];

  // mutate/reduce the input value's copy while looking
  // for the array where its last item matches the first
  // item of the previously found/extracted (linked) array.
  while (list.length !== 0) {

    itemListIndex = list.findIndex(aList =>
      aList[aList.length - 1] === firstItem 
    );
    itemList = list.splice(itemListIndex, 1)[0]; // mutate/reduce.
    result.unshift(itemList); // aggregate return value.

    firstItem = itemList[0];
  }
  return result;
}

const arr = [
  ['butter', 'jelly'],
  ['bananas', 'apples'],
  ['peanuts', 'butter'],
  ['jelly', 'bananas'],
];
console.log(
  'original :: arr :',
  arr
);
console.log(
  'sorted :: getCopyInDominoesLikeOrder(arr) :',
  getCopyInDominoesLikeOrder(arr)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you only need to extract the first element from each array in the sort callback, then return the lexiographic difference:

```js
const arr = [['c','d'], ['a','b'], ['d','e'], ['b','c']];

arr.sort((a, b) => a[0].localeCompare(b[0]));
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: I'm so sorry, first example wasn't informative for my real case. Please, check updated question. For ['a', 'b'] case your answer works perfectly!

Answer (score -2):

```
.sort(([a], [b]) => a > b)
```

Comment: The '>' operator is not suitable in this case. I updated my question